# PhpStorm: In-time text replacing

Tags: replace, phpstorm, text-processing

I want PhpStorm print `->` always, when I insert just `-` (so no need for `Shift + .`)

Is there any build-in solution? If no, probably someone can suggest a software for Ubuntu, that would do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any build-in solution

Yes, but it works only after `$this`.

For other object instances watch https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-28351 ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.

---

Possible workaround -- record a macro that will type `->` and assign a shortcut to it. Then just use that when you need typing `->`. No other bright ideas (using IDE functionality only).